# How to verify password against salted hash with PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a password hash generated like:

```
$ mkpasswd -m sha-256 -S `printf "%x%x" $RANDOM $RANDOM` 'blah'
$5$1c741b59$FBGE9z1jHJU8Njb5JkAwxdI2ock/kcgoxll8f.fdTI3
```

I have table with login name and the password value that matches the string above.

Now I need to verify that user's provided password mathes the hash with a PostgreSQL query.

I am able to extract salt with regexp_matches function but don't know how to proceed further.

Can someone help or direct me to some relevant tutorial?

I have sha256_crypt function available but I am stuck on writing appropriate query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to make a function and verify password with it. It will also handle optional '{SHA256-CRYPT}' prefix and specified number of rounds in -R parameter (if any) for mkpasswd:
Here is the result

```
~$ mkpasswd -m sha-256 -S `printf "%x%x" $RANDOM $RANDOM` 'blah'
$5$51486e19$l8NKop8WQYo4xhmjl/Wt1T25VMLqM8Qg9/YcYy0VYg5
~$ psql test
psql (9.6.11)
Type "help" for help.

test=# CREATE EXTENSION shacrypt;
CREATE EXTENSION
test=# create table test (login varchar(128),passwd varchar(256));
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into test values ('user123','$5$51486e19$l8NKop8WQYo4xhmjl/Wt1T25VMLqM8Qg9/YcYy0VYg5');
INSERT 0 1
test=# CREATE LANGUAGE plperl;
CREATE LANGUAGE
test=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha256_verify (varchar, varchar) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    $_[0] =~ m/^(?:{SHA256-CRYPT})?(\$\d+\$(?:rounds=\d+\$)?[^\$]+)\$(.*)/;
    my ($s,$h1)=($1,$2);
    my $q="SELECT sha256_crypt(\'$_[1]\',\'$s\')";
    my $rv = spi_exec_query($q);
    my $h2 = $rv->{rows}[0]->{sha256_crypt};
    $h2 =~ m/^(\$\d+\$(?:rounds=\d+\$)?[^\$]+)\$(.*)/;
    $h2=$2;
    return 1 if ($h1 =~ m/$h2/);
    return 0;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
CREATE FUNCTION
test=# select login from test where login='user123' and sha256_verify(passwd,'blah');
  login  
---------
 user123
(1 row)

test=# select login from test where login='user123' and sha256_verify(passwd,'blahblah');
 login 
-------
(0 rows)
```